# sum the count_value of two ( col) in python panda as the following

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| col1 | col2 | value_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 100 |
| B | A | 200 |

I need to convert to

| col1 | col2 | value_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 300 |

Answer (score 0):

Let's add another row to make it a bit more interesting, and load the df

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
'''
col1    col2    value_count
A   B   100
B   A   200
C   A   300
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\s+')
df
```

The idea is to stick 'col1', 'col2' into a sorted tuple and then groupby on that and sum-aggregating. We have to use a tuple to be able to aggregate by that

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.apply(lambda row: tuple(sorted((row['col1'],row['col2']))), axis=1)).sum().reset_index()
```

df2 looks like this:

```
    index         value_count
--  ----------  -------------
 0  ('A', 'B')            300
 1  ('A', 'C')            300
```

Now we need to expand 'index' into individual columns

```
df2[['col1','col2']] = df2['index'].apply(pd.Series)
df2.drop(columns = 'index')
```

and we get

```
      value_count  col1    col2
--  -------------  ------  ------
 0            300  A       B
 1            300  A       C
```